# exec.Command call java cli

Tags: go, command-line-interface

How can I make the exec.Command command call a command from another file?

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Iniciando...")
    command := exec.Command("java -version")
    command.Dir = "."
    output, err := command.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Erro: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", output)

}
```

Erro:  exec: "java -version": executable file not found in $PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each argument needs to be in its own separate string. Try `exec.Command("java", "-version")`