# Is it possible to run 'kubectl get events' from golang code

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to get the list of kubernetes events and store it, how can I run 'kubectl get events' from a golang code.

I tried the below but getting "exec: "kubectl get events": executable file not found in $PATHCommand Successfully Executed"

```
package main
  
import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
//    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("kubectl get events").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Command Successfully Executed")
    output := string(out[:])
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an official go client instead https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exec.Command call java cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011424/exec-command-call-java-cli)

Comment: Your error shows that you tried to do a `exec.Command("kubectl get events")` but the code that you posted doesn't match that error - the code that you posted to execute `"ls"` works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would heed @zerkms 's advice and query any `k8s` info with the [go-client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) - doing so will make it much easier to extract data rather than dealing with messy command-line output parsing/error-checking.

---

If you must `exec` to an external program, ensure you use [exec.Command](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command) correctly, listing the executable and its individual arguments as [variadic arguments](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

```
out, err := exec.Command("kubectl", "get", "events").Output()
```

calling:

```
exec.Command("kubectl get events")
```

fails, as it tries to find a single executable file in your path called `kubectl get events` instead of the intended `kubectl` command.